# discord.js http request/status

Tags: http, request, discord.js

I have a question.
How do I check the status of a website?

What do I need?
I just want to code the command /status. As soon as a user types this command, the bot should send a embed with the following text:
Website-Status: ONLINE/OFFLINE
Server-Status: ONLINE/OFFLINE

I need help :D

Answer (score 0):

Using the [ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping) module on npm, you can do this easily.

```js
const { sys } = require('ping');
sys.probe('HOSTNAME / IP', (isAlive) => {
    if(isAlive) {
        // Code if true.
    } else {
        // Code if false.
    }
});
```